# Projectile motion dependency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, vectors, projectile, coordinate-systems

I have read that in projectile motion both vertical and horizontal components are independent of each other but i don't get it that how it is possible i think that they are dependent. If they are not could someone explain with a mathematical relation.

Comment: Newton's second law in vector notation.

Comment: @CuriousOne but can you give me physical and observable example that how is this possible and also don't get the idea from newton second law in vector notation that how is this possible.

Comment: Do you understand the linearity of vectors and what linear independence means? That's the reason why vectors make a good description for classical mechanics, where we find experimentally that the vector components of free motion in orthogonal directions are independent. What might get you confused is when we have to look at motion in a potential. It's the potential that breaks the symmetry of free space and then, you are correct, any displacement in one direction can have consequences for the forces acting in a different direction. That we can describe with differential equations.

Comment: Note that air resistance can (does in some regimes) also break the non-dependence that we teach at the physics 101 level. None the less, you need to work on understanding the air-resistance free system because in doing so you will get the beginnings of a working intuition for vectors.

Comment: @CuriousOne@dmckee thanks for helping me out of this problem and can you guys vote for this question because it would help later next year for entrance examination otherwise this question would be get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Let the velocity at instant be v(vector) = (Vx) i + (Vy) j. i and j denote unit vectors, along x and y axis respectively. dv/dt = a(acceleration) = - gj. dv/dt = [(Vx(final) -Vx(initial))i + (Vy(final) - Vy(initial))j]/dt = - gj. By initial and final I mean Vx and Vy at time t and t + dt. As the resulatant is only along the y axis the X component must be 0 ie Vx(final) = Vx(initial). Hence it can be said that since the acceleration is only along the y axis, it acts only on Vy and not on Vx, and Vx will be a constant throughout. Hence you can say that Vx and Vy are independent of each other as Vy won't change as Vx changes, and even Vx won't change as Vy changes, during the motion.

Answer (score 1):

What you have read is only valid in a vacuum. With [air resistance](http://yukterez.net/ballistik/#plot) the drag is a function of the total velocity, so in reality the deceleration on each axis also depends on the other.